# Is there a function that is the envelope of the sum of ceilings of reciprocal functions

Tags: functions, curves, ceiling-and-floor-functions, envelope

TL;DR:

Given a sum of ceilings of reciprocal functions

$$y_1 = T = \sum^{n-1}_i \Big\lceil \frac{p_i}{k} \Big\rceil$$

is there a corresponding form for a function that envelopes the $T$ on the left? Or in other words, is there a form for the function $L$ that touches the left endpoint of each line segment in the graph of $y_1 = T$?

More formally,

Given $y_2 = h$ for some integer $h$, we have that $y_1$ and $y_2$ intersect in a line segment, say at $y=h$ from $x=x_{h^-}$ to $x=x_{h^+}$. The left envelope of $y_1 = T$ would be the function $L$ such that for each integer $h$, we have $L(x_{h^-}) = h$ or in other words for each integer $h$, we have $L(x) = h$ iff $x = x_{h^-}$.

For example, in this [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uvz2rkqbml), we have

$$
y_1 = T =
\Big\lceil \frac{3}{x} \Big\rceil
+ \Big\lceil \frac{6}{x} \Big\rceil
+ \Big\lceil \frac{7}{x} \Big\rceil
+ \Big\lceil \frac{11}{x} \Big\rceil
$$

and $y_1 = T$ intersects $y_2 = h = 8$ in a line segment at $y = 8$ from $x=x_{h^-}=3.667$ to $x=x_{h^+}=5.5$. The left envelope of this $T$ would have $L(3.667) = 8$.

---

Given a sum of two reciprocals

$$
T_2 =
\Big\lceil \frac{p_0}{k} \Big\rceil
+ \Big\lceil \frac{p_1}{k} \Big\rceil
$$

we can note that $p_0 = ak + b$ and $p_1 = ck + d$ for some integers $0 \leq b, d < k$ and so we have

$$
\Big\lceil \frac{ak + b}{k} \Big\rceil =
\begin{cases}
a & \text{if } b = 0\\
a+1 & \text{if } b \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

and similarly for $p_1$.

Overall we have four cases for the value of $T_2$:

|  | $d = 0$ | $d \neq 0$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $b = 0$ | $a+c$ | $a+(c+1)$ |
| $b \neq 0$ | $(a+1)+c$ | $(a+1)+(c+1)$ |

Note, asking whether $b = 0$ or $b \neq 0$ is the same as asking whether $p_0$ is divisible by $k$ or not, respectively.

We can express the above in python3 as follows:

```
a, b = divmod(p[0], k)
c, d = divmod(p[1], k)
T = a + (b != 0) + c + (d != 0)

# Alternative
# T = a + bool(b) + c + bool(d)
```

Also, each time we add a $\big\lceil \frac{p_i}{k} \big\rceil$ term to the $T$ sum, we introduce two new cases (i.e. whether $p_i$ is divisible by $k$ or not). Thus a $T$ sum of $n$ terms would have $2^n$ cases. Is there any way around this? Perhaps there's a more clever way to combine terms...???

---

Motivating problem:

I was doing [Leetcode #875: Koko Eating Bananas](https://leetcode.com/problems/koko-eating-bananas/) (description in footnote [1]).

The answer can be found using binary search over $k_{min} <= k <= k_{max}$ where `k_min = sum(piles) / h` and `k_max = max(piles)` (see footnote [2]), but I was wondering if there's an even more mathematical way to find it.

Having chosen a $k$, $p_i = $`pile[i]` takes $t_i = \big\lceil \frac{p_i}{k} \big\rceil$ hours to consume and all $n$ piles take

$$T = \sum^{n-1}_i \Big\lceil \frac{p_i}{k} \Big\rceil$$

hours to consume. We want to minimize $k$ such that $T \leq h$.

This can be done graphically:

---

Given example 1:

```
Input: piles = [3,6,7,11], h = 8
Output: 4
```

We graph

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1 = T &= \sum^{n-1}_i \Big\lceil \frac{p_i}{x} \Big\rceil\\
&=
\Big\lceil \frac{3}{x} \Big\rceil
+ \Big\lceil \frac{6}{x} \Big\rceil
+ \Big\lceil \frac{7}{x} \Big\rceil
+ \Big\lceil \frac{11}{x} \Big\rceil
\end{aligned}
$$

where $p_i$ represents `piles[i]`, $y$ represents `T`, and $x$ represents `k`. We also graph $y_2 \leq h$ to represent the constraint. The minimum value of $k$ is minimum value of $x$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ intersect.

See the [Example 1 Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uvz2rkqbml), which shows the minimum value of $k$ is $3.667$, though since the problem statement calls for $k$ being an integer, the actual value is $4$.

---

Here is another examples:

```
Input: piles = [30,11,23,4,20], h = 6
Output: 23
```

Likewise, here's the [Example 3 Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/an8wsbqlaz), which shows the minimum value of $k$ is $23$.

---

[1]: [Leetcode #875: Koko Eating Bananas](https://leetcode.com/problems/koko-eating-bananas/)

> Koko loves to eat bananas. There are $n$ piles of bananas, the $i$th pile
> has `piles[i]` bananas (`piles` is $0$-indexed). The guards have gone and will come back in $h$
> hours.
>
> Koko can decide her bananas-per-hour eating speed of $k$. Each hour, she
> chooses some pile of bananas and eats $k$ bananas from that pile. If the
> pile has less than $k$ bananas, she eats all of them instead and will
> not eat any more bananas during this hour.
>
> Koko likes to eat slowly but still wants to finish eating all the
> bananas before the guards return.
>
> Return the minimum integer $k$ such that she can eat all the bananas
> within $h$ hours.

[2]: Binary Search solution

```
class Solution:
    def minEatingSpeed(self, piles: List[int], h: int) -> int:
        k_min = (sum(piles) + h-1) // h # ceil(sum(piles) / h) 
        k_max = max(piles)
        
        l, r = k_min, k_max + 1
        while l < r:
            k = (l+r) // 2
            t = sum((p + k-1) // k for p in piles) # sum(ceil(p / k) for p in piles)
            if t <= h:
                r = k
            else: # t > h
                l = k + 1
        return l
```